# Не могу подключить папки js Bootstrap5

Tags: python, django, bootstrap5

Несколько дней я пытаюсь подключить папки js, css работает. Разделять по папкам css и js тоже пробовала, никак. Мой файл находиться не в index.html, а в stock.html. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что здесь не так. Я делаю карусель для товаров

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    {% load static %}

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel = "stylesheet"  href="{% static 'boar/css/index.css' %}">
    <link rel = "stylesheet"  href="{% static 'boar/css/style-stock-content.css' %}">
    <link rel = "stylesheet"  href="{% static 'boar/css/style-about-content.css' %}">
    <link rel = "stylesheet"  href="{% static 'boar/css/style-news-content.css' %}">



       <link rel = "stylesheet"  href="{% static 'boar/bootstrap/owl.carousel.min.css' %}">
    <link rel = "stylesheet"  href="{% static 'boar/bootstrap/owl.theme.default.min.css' %}">

    <script src="{% static 'boar/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'boar/bootstrap/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'boar/bootstrap/main.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'boar/bootstrap/owl.carousel.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'boar/bootstrap/popper.js' %}"></script>

    <title>{% block title %}Главная страница{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Шапка -->
<header>
    <div class = "header-background"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/header-background.png' %}"/></div>
    <a href = "{% url 'home' %}"><div class = "menu-home">Главная</div></a>
    <a href = "{% url 'stock' %}"><div class = "menu-stock">Склад</div></a>
    <a href = "{% url 'about' %}"><div class = "menu-about">О нас</div></a>
    <a href = "{% url 'news' %}"><div class = "menu-news">Новости</div></a>
    <div class = "logo"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/Logo.png' %}"/></div>

    <div class = "insta"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/Insta.png' %}"/></div>
    <div class = "twit"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/twit.png' %}"/></div>
    <div class = "vk"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/vk.png' %}"/></div>

    <div class = "ikon-phone"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/ikon-phone.png' %}"/></div>
    <div class = "ikon-maps"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/maps-ikon.png' %}"/></div>

    <div class = "WhatTele">WhatsApp|Telegram</div>
    <div class = "number">+8(000)000-00-00</div>

    <div class = "address">Адрес</div>
    <div class = "add">Россия, г.Москва, ул. Кирова, д 16</div>
</header>
    <!-- Основной контент -->
{% block content %}
<div class = "text-process">Как происходит процесс изготовления консервов?</div>

    <div class = "proc1"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/pig.png' %}"/></div>
    <div class = "text_proc1">На нашей ферме мы отбираем самый лучший домашний скот. Самых крупных и самых откормленных</div>

    <div class = "proc2"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/zerno.png' %}"/></div>
    <div class = "text_proc2">На следующем этапе мы откармливаем наш скот специальными натуральными кормами для обогощения полезными витаминами и лучшего роста
    </div>

    <div class = "proc3"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/meat.png' %}"/></div>
    <div class = "text_proc3">Из отобранного мяса мы изготавливаем консервы, предварительно пройдя проверку на наличие болезней и обработав от химикатов</div>

    <div class = "proc4"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/conserv.png' %}"/></div>
    <div class = "text_proc4">Вуаля! Продукт готов! Мясо хранится в плотно упакованных банках. Могут хранится очень много лет и не портится. А главное сохраняет свое качество на долгие годы!</div>

    <div class = "line1"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/line.png' %}"/></div>

    <div class = "text-cho-o_nas">Что о нас говорят?</div>

    <div class = "photo1"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/photo-comment_1.png' %}"/></div>
    <div class = "name1">Николай</div>
    <div class = "text_comment1">Один мой знакомый посоветоал мне этот сайт. Сначало у меня было недоверие, но позже решил заказать несколько баночек со свининой. Вкус был невероятный, мягкий и нежный</div>

    <div class = "photo2"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/photo-comment_2.png' %}"/></div>
    <div class = "name2">Андрей</div>
    <div class = "text_comment2">Случайно увидел этот сайт. Меня привлекло название “Кабанчик”, а также большое любопытство. Решил попробовать заказать баночку консервов. Доставка была быстрой доставили все в целости. Качество оказалось великолепным. В ближайшем времени буду еще за
        казывать на этом сайте</div>

    <div class = "photo3"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/photo-comment_3.png' %}"/></div>
    <div class = "name3">Елена</div>
    <div class = "text_comment3">Я очень люблю консервы, но в последнее время они стали слишком дорогие. Решила попробовать заказать через интернет-магазин на часной ферме. Попробовала и поняла, что теперь я буду заказывать т сюда</div>

    <div class = "line2"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/line.png' %}"/></div>

    <div class = "text-poch-sto">Почему стоит выбрать нас?</div>

    <div class = "photo-gmo"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/ikon-gmo.png' %}"/></div>
    <div class = "text_gmo">Наутуральный продукт, без ГМО</div>

    <div class = "photo-dost"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/ikon-dost.png' %}"/></div>
    <div class = "text_dost">Быстрая доставка от 2 часов до 3 дней</div>

    <div class = "photo-price"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/ikon-price.png' %}"/></div>
    <div class = "text_price">Продукт по очень низкой цене</div>

    <div class = "photo-money"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/ikon-money.png' %}"/></div>
    <div class = "text_money">Вернем деньги наличными или на карту</div>
{% endblock content%}
 <!-- Подвал -->
<footer>
    <div class = "footer-background"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/footer-background.png' %}"/></div>

    <div class = "inst-footer"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/insta-footer.png' %}"/></div>
    <div class = "twit-footer"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/twit-footer.png' %}"/></div>
    <div class = "vk-footer"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/vk-footer.png' %}"/></div>

    <div class = "ikon-maps-footer"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/maps-ikon-footer.png' %}"/></div>
    <div class = "ikon-phone-footer"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/ikon-phone-footer.png' %}"/></div>

    <div class = "WhatTele-footer">WhatsApp|Telegram</div>
    <div class = "number-footer">+8(000)000-00-00</div>

    <div class = "address-footer">Адрес</div>
    <div class = "add-footer">Россия, г.Москва, ул. Кирова, д 16</div>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

stock.html

```html
{% extends 'boar/index.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% static 'boar/css/index.css' %}
{% static 'boar/css/style-stock-content.css' %}

{% static 'boar/bootstrap/owl.carousel.min.css' %}
{% static 'boar/bootstrap/owl.theme.default.min.css' %}

{% static 'boar/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js' %}
{% static 'boar/bootstrap/jquery.min.js' %}
{% static 'boar/bootstrap/main.js' %}
{% static 'boar/bootstrap/owl.carousel.min.js' %}
{% static 'boar/bootstrap/popper.js' %}

{% block title %}Склад{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<section class="ftco-section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="featured-carousel owl-carousel">
          <div class = "carou">
            <div class="item">
              <div class="work-wrap d-md-flex">
                <div class = "stock-product-1"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product1.png' %}"/></div>
                <div class = "stock-product-1-text">Мясо кролика Мкк Балтийский в собственном соку 325 г</div>
                <div class = "canva1"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png '%}"/></div>
                <div class = "price1">325 руб</div>
                
                
                
                <div class = "stock-product-2"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product2.png' %}"/></div>
                <div class = "stock-product-2-text">Говядина Главпродукт тушеная экстра 525 г</div>
                <div class = "canva2"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                <div class = "price2">240 руб</div>
                
                
                
                <div class = "stock-product-3"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product3.png ' %}"/></div>
                <div class = "stock-product-3-text">Цыпленок тушеный Батькин резерв филе в собственном соку 338 г</div>
                <div class = "canva3"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                <div class = "price3">320 руб</div>
                
                
                
                <div class = "stock-product-4"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product4.png' %}"/></div>
                <div class = "stock-product-4-text">Свинина тушеная Семейный запас 525 г</div>
                <div class = "canva4"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                <div class = "price4">200 руб</div>
                
                
                
                <div class = "stock-product-5"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product5.png' %}"/></div>
                <div class = "stock-product-5-text">Говядина тушеная Батькин резерв 338 г</div>
                <div class = "canva5"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                <div class = "price5">425 руб</div>
                
                
                
                <div class = "stock-product-6"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product6.png' %}"/></div>
                <div class = "stock-product-6-text">Тушенка Aro кусковая свинина 340 г</div>
                <div class = "canva6"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                <div class = "price6">525 руб</div>
                
                
                
                <div class = "stock-product-7"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product7.png' %}"/></div>
                <div class = "stock-product-7-text">Говядина тушеная БКК Золото Байкала тушеная ГОСТ в собственном соку 338 г</div>
                
                
                
                <div class = "stock-product-8"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product8.png' %}"/></div>
                <div class = "stock-product-8-text">Свинина Мясной Союз тушеная кусковая 340 г</div>
                
                
                <div class = "stock-product-9"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product9.png' %}"/></div>
                <div class = "stock-product-9-text">Свинина тушеная Таврия ГОСТ 338 г</div>
  
                <div class = "button">
  
                <div class = "canva7"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                <div class = "price7">325 руб</div>
  
                <div class = "canva8"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                <div class = "price8">150 руб</div>
  
                <div class = "canva9"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                <div class = "price9">325 руб</div>
                </div>
                
                </div>
              </div>
  
              <div class="item">
                <div class="work-wrap d-md-flex">
                  <div class = "stock-product-1"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product1.png' %}"/></div>
                  <div class = "stock-product-1-text">Мясо кролика Мкк Балтийский в собственном соку 325 г</div>
                  <div class = "canva1"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png '%}"/></div>
                  <div class = "price1">325 руб</div>
                  
                  
                  
                  <div class = "stock-product-2"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product2.png' %}"/></div>
                  <div class = "stock-product-2-text">Говядина Главпродукт тушеная экстра 525 г</div>
                  <div class = "canva2"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                  <div class = "price2">240 руб</div>
                  
                  
                  
                  <div class = "stock-product-3"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product3.png ' %}"/></div>
                  <div class = "stock-product-3-text">Цыпленок тушеный Батькин резерв филе в собственном соку 338 г</div>
                  <div class = "canva3"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                  <div class = "price3">320 руб</div>
                  
                  
                  
                  <div class = "stock-product-4"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product4.png' %}"/></div>
                  <div class = "stock-product-4-text">Свинина тушеная Семейный запас 525 г</div>
                  <div class = "canva4"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                  <div class = "price4">200 руб</div>
                  
                  
                  
                  <div class = "stock-product-5"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product5.png' %}"/></div>
                  <div class = "stock-product-5-text">Говядина тушеная Батькин резерв 338 г</div>
                  <div class = "canva5"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                  <div class = "price5">425 руб</div>
                  
                  
                  
                  <div class = "stock-product-6"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product6.png' %}"/></div>
                  <div class = "stock-product-6-text">Тушенка Aro кусковая свинина 340 г</div>
                  <div class = "canva6"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                  <div class = "price6">525 руб</div>
                  
                  
                  
                  <div class = "stock-product-7"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product7.png' %}"/></div>
                  <div class = "stock-product-7-text">Говядина тушеная БКК Золото Байкала тушеная ГОСТ в собственном соку 338 г</div>
                  
                  
                  
                  <div class = "stock-product-8"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product8.png' %}"/></div>
                  <div class = "stock-product-8-text">Свинина Мясной Союз тушеная кусковая 340 г</div>
                  
                  
                  <div class = "stock-product-9"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product9.png' %}"/></div>
                  <div class = "stock-product-9-text">Свинина тушеная Таврия ГОСТ 338 г</div>
    
                  <div class = "button">
    
                  <div class = "canva7"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                  <div class = "price7">325 руб</div>
    
                  <div class = "canva8"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                  <div class = "price8">150 руб</div>
    
                  <div class = "canva9"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                  <div class = "price9">325 руб</div>
                  </div>
                  
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  
{% endblock content %}
```

settings.py

```py
"""
Django settings for ShopBoar project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.0.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-0l_awyr8&ftgoddwmytwhg09iou2norfz(a_0zb^o*s3xh&^ei'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'bootstrap5',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ShopBoar.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'boar/templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ShopBoar.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "boar/static"),
]

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда Вы используете  `{% extends 'index.html' %}` все стили из шаблона `index.html` наследуются автоматически.

Вам достаточно прописать в `index.html` все из бутстрапа по документации.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```